# Power button shuts down computer without asking for confirmation?

Tags: kubuntu, shutdown

I upgraded to Kubuntu 13.04 on a Dell Vostro 1510. When I press my power button on the laptop, Kubuntu does not ask me a confirmation but shuts down the latptop directly.

How can I make it prompt me with a confirmation?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with 13.10.I just removed the last line from /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh and I got the the confirmation screen back.

Answer (score 1):

In a terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh
```

on the last line you should find `/sbin/shutdown -h now`

replace with `/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper`

(not sure this will be very eye-candy in KDE though)

Comment: Isn't there an equivalent for KDE? I had a prompt in 12.04, why is it gone?